# An involved Feynman integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration

Working with QCD, I have found the following integral from Feynman diagrams to solve
$$
I(p)=\int\frac{d^4p_1}{(2\pi)^4}\int\frac{d^4p_2}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{p_2^2-m_0^2} \left(\frac{p\cdot p_1-p_1\cdot p_2}{M^2}-1\right)
\frac{\sqrt{(p-p_1)\cdot(p_1-p_2)}}{p_1^2-M^2}.
$$
I have tried different tricks but the square root seems to imply a difficult complication to evade. Is there any way to manage it?

Also, I am interested at a small momenta behaviour.

Comment: Where does the square root come from in terms of diagrams?

Comment: I have a term like ${\bar u}(p')\gamma_\mu u(p)$ that, with Gordon decomposition, yields ${\bar u}(p')(p'_\mu+p_\mu) u(p)$. The anti-symmetric term does not contribute. Then, ${\bar u}(p')u(p)=\sqrt{p'\cdot p}$.

Comment: which momenta being small are you concerned with $p, p_1, p_2$ ?

Comment: So the $u(p)$ are coming from external legs right? They shouldn't appear in the loops of your diagram right?

Comment: @InertialObserver I mean $p$.

Comment: @octonion It is difficult to explain but this is the correction to the gluon propagator coming from the quark fields. So, it is something like ${\bar u}(x')\gamma_\nu S(x'-x'')\gamma^\nu u(x)$ under integration.